# WordPress WP_Query: Display custom post type based on custom meta value, and also order on another custom meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the WordPress plug-ins [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), and [Custom Post Type UI](http://webdevstudios.com/plugin/custom-post-type-ui/).

I have built a WP_Query to display a particular post type, filtered by a particular custom field value.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'news', 
    'meta_key' => 'news_story_type', 
    'meta_value' => 'release', 
    'posts_per_page' => 3 
) );
```

I now want to sort the resulting posts by another custom field, `date_of_publication` rather than use WordPress's menu_order or date. The [ACF documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/) says to specify `orderby` and `meta_key` in the query args.

> $args = array(
>
> 'post_type'     => 'event',
>
> 'posts_per_page'    => -1,
>
> 'meta_key'      => 'start_date',
>
> 'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
>
> 'order'         => 'DESC' );

But alas, doing so conflicts with the `meta_key` I've already supplied to filter.

Has anyone encountered this before and found a solution?

Comment: [You may check this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67600/meta-query-sorting-by-2-keys).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using meta_query

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'news', 
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array('key' => 'news_story_type', 'value' => 'release')
     )
) );
```

Comment: the same code I apply to my WP_Query but couldn't work for me. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53722553/get-the-custom-post-type-data-using-a-custom-field-value-in-wordpress