# get the custom post type data using a custom field value in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

Can I get the data using custom field value? My `post_type` is `brand-name` and the field name is `generic-name`. So How can I get all the data using the `generic-name`?

Here is the code:

```
$title = get_the_title(); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
          'posts_per_page'=>9,
          'post_type'=>'brand-name',
          'order'   => 'ASC',
          'meta_query' => array(
           array(
                'key' => 'generic-name',// this key is advance custom field: type post_object
                'value' => $title,
                'type'  => 'char' // type not working
           ), 
        ), 
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) 
      );`
```

This code was not working.

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

Comment: I already query like this but its not working

Comment: Modify your meta query to include comparision operator as follow: `'meta_query' => array(
       array(
            'key' => 'generic-name',
            'value' => $custom_field_value,
           'compare' => '='
       ),`

Comment: see the latest post i edited it. i use type option but type value not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AFC field is a post object, which means the meta value is either a single post id, or a serialized array of post ids.

If your custom field is set to only allow a single selection, then it will be a single id, and can be queried like this:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID(); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
      'posts_per_page'=>9,
      'post_type'=>'brand-name',
      'order'   => 'ASC',
      'meta_query' => array(
       array(
            'key' => 'generic-name',// this key is advance custom field: type post_object
            'value' => $post_id,
       ), 
    ), 
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) 
  );`
```

If your custom field allows multiple selection, then it will a serialized php array of ids. Since mysql does not know how to read php serialized data, the best you can do is use a `LIKE` query:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID(); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
      'posts_per_page'=>9,
      'post_type'=>'brand-name',
      'order'   => 'ASC',
      'meta_query' => array(
       array(
            'key' => 'generic-name',// this key is advance custom field: type post_object
            'value' => sprintf("\"%s\"", $post_id),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
       ), 
    ), 
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) 
  );`
```

Comment: Great, glad i could help you

Comment: yeah, this also helps for me after two more days.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you. Please have a look at this.

Can I get the data using custom field value? -- Yes, you can get the data using custom field value.

First, we can get the custom field value by using the below code.

```
 <?php $custom_field_value= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'generic-name', true ); ?>
```

This $custom_field_value return the value of 'generic-name' field.

By using that value we can form WP_Query.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
      'posts_per_page'=>9,
      'post_type'=>'brand-name',
      'order'   => 'ASC',
      'meta_query' => array(
       array(
            'key' => 'generic-name',
            'value' => $custom_field_value
       ), 
    ), 
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) 
  );
```

Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question. My value will be my pages title. So?

Comment: Is any of your post has meta-key as 'generic-name' and meta-value as your title?

Comment: If I use `meta_key` and `meta_value` then it returns all the value of `brand-name` post. but I want only the data which value is matched by `$title`. And the `key` doesn't return any value. this is my main problem

Comment: I do not think so, but I may be wrong.
May I know what do you expect the 'key' will return?
Already you defined a key as 'generic-name'.

Comment: key means my field name is `generic-name` so what can i add key or else?

Comment: Can you please try this below code first,
`$args = array(
'post_type' => 'brand-name',
'meta_query' => array( array(
        'key' => 'generic-name',
        'value' => $title ))
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);`

If it works means, try to add the pagination and order functionality.

Comment: this is same thing what i wrote. not working can you please check this to my pc

Comment: Sabbir, is your variable `$title` return any value?

Comment: title returns the title of the page but when I use `key` it can not return any data but `meta_key` returns all of data

Comment: I got the data if its text field but my generic-name is advanced custom fields post_object type

Comment: `array('key' => 'brand-name-products','value' => '500mg','type' => 'NUMERIC','compare' => '=');` <==this is works But My custom field type is `post object` So what is `post_object` type

Comment: May I know where you placed this code? in functions.php or single.php or something else.

Comment: singe-{custom-post-type}.php page

Comment: If i use the accurate type in meta_query It will be works So let me know the type

Comment: Refer this below link.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

They mentioned about compare option. Just try with `=`

Comment: see my latest edit post I use like this my it wrong only type option